# Return statement in c

Tags: c, return, return-value

In this code when I write the return statement without "bonues" variable, the answer is 3750. When write it, it give 4750.

So why the if statement won't be excuted without writing the `bonues` variable??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int calcbouns(int yearworks); 

int main() 
{    
    int employee_one =calcbouns (15);    
    printf("%d",employee_one);    
    return 0 ;
} 

int calcbouns(int yearworks)
{    
    int bonues = yearworks*250;    
    if (yearworks>10) 
    {
        bonues +=1000;
    }
    return bonues ;
}
```

Comment: "why the if statement won't be excuted without writing the "bonues" variable" that's not what is happening. By returning without a return value you're invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, when the compiler gives you a warning, you should really listen to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`calcbouns` is a function specified as returning an integer. When you write `return bonues ;`, the return value of the function is specified as the value of `bonus`.

When you write `return ;` you are violating a language constraint. An "empty" return statement cannot appear in a non-void function. To do otherwise results in your program having undefined behavior. And one aspect of undefined behavior is weird return values.

Conclusion? Don't violate language constraints, and compile with all warnings enabled (possibly even treat them as errors), so that your compiler could better protect you from constraint violations.

Answer (score 0):

So you say:"if i write `return bonues;` it returns 4750 and if I only write `return;` it returns 3750?

You should always say *what* you want to return. If you have warnings turned on you will probaby get a warning.

But what happens is, if you are on the Intel x86 platform, that the return value of a function is placed in the `eax` register. So you return what was currently in the `eax` register, which turns out to be the value of`bonues` before anything has been added to it.